# FTP with IIS Authentication manager

Tags: iis, ftp

I am trying to create an FTP site in IIS, which will contain folders based on IIS isolated users.
I don't want these user to be Windows Users.

I have read many different forums which all provided the same steps, such as

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7

But for some reason the users i'm creating are not able to log in. I get Access Denied. Although at some points i removed all firewalls and added every kind of permission on the folders and such.

I tried the above suggested steps for 100 times.

Could anyone might suggest something that i might be missing?

Comment: FWIW, on local intranet sites I've worked with I just used Filezilla Server instead of IIS. Simplifies things so much.

Comment: does FileZilla server work through internet? I need it publicly accessible @charles

Comment: Yeah, there shouldn't be any limitation for that.

Comment: Wow Great. Forget IIS. Filezilla server installed and configured in 30 seconds. 10x @charles

Comment: Yep, I hesitate to call this an answer to the question though, since its nothing to do with what you asked.

Comment: Try this http://www.websitepanel.net/documentation/deployment-guide/server-configuration/configuring-windows-2008-web-server/